# activemq broker постоянное переподключение к разным брокерам без необходимости

Tags: java, spring, activemq

Имеется 2 сервера(amq1,amq2) с развернутыми ActiveMQ. Cервис, который создает очереди, находится на третьем сервере.

в настрйоках подключения я указал `spring.activemq.broker-url: failover:(ssl://amq1:61616,ssl://amq1:61616)`

Оба сервера работают корректно и не теряют соединения.

Проблема в том, что сервис сначала подключается по приоритету к amq1, но иногда меняет подключение на amq2, потом снова возвращается к первому. 
В логах нет сообщения о том, что коннект к amq1 пропал.

```
INFO 24003 --- [ActiveMQ Task-1] o.a.a.t.failover.FailoverTransport   : Successfully connected to ssl://amq2:61616  
INFO 24003 --- [ActiveMQ Task-1] o.a.a.t.failover.FailoverTransport       : Successfully connected to ssl://amq2:61616  
INFO 24003 --- [ActiveMQ Task-1] o.a.a.t.failover.FailoverTransport       : Successfully connected to ssl://amq1:61616 
ERROR 24003 --- [http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-4] r.o.RestExceptionHandler  : dm.exception.ActiveMQException: Failed get JMS response:  
INFO 24003 --- [ActiveMQ Task-1] o.a.a.t.failover.FailoverTransport       : Successfully connected to ssl://amq2:61616  
INFO 24003 --- [ActiveMQ Task-1] o.a.a.t.failover.FailoverTransport       : Successfully connected to ssl://amq1:61616
```

Как можно сделать так, чтобы прдключение к amq2 было только в том случае, если amq1 перестал отвечать?

p.s. если указать только один amq сервер, то когда пропадает подключение, spring  10 раз по умолчанию пытается переподключиться. Хотелось бы, чтобы после после 10 раза сменил подключение на amq2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

необходимо в конекшн добавить `failover:(ssl://amq1:61616,ssl://amq1:61616)?randomize=false&priorityBackup=true`

если коротко, то "использовать приоритет по порядку, переподключиться назад всегда, если доступен брокер"

из [документации](http://activemq.apache.org/failover-transport-reference.html) следует

priorityBackup=true

> Given this URL a client will try to connect and stay connected to the
>   local broker. If local broker fails, it will of course fail over to
>   remote. However, as priorityBackup parameter is used, the client will
>   constantly try to reconnect to local. Once the client can do so, the
>   client will re-connect to it without any need for manual intervention.

randomize=false

> The Failover transport chooses a URI at random by default. This
>   effectively load-balances clients over multiple brokers. However, to
>   have a client connect to a primary first and only connect to a
>   secondary backup broker when the primary is unavailable, set
>   randomize=false.